# How to remove Developer tools changes redundancy

Tags: javascript, html, css, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

Is there a way to hide the red text or changes in developer tools?

I tried everything I know but it still there.

[image]

how to remove the red padding-tops

Comment: What have you tried? Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score -2):

Disabling the developer tools is difficult but you can do it: Open Chrome (Or Chromium). Open the developer tools by pressing F12 and resize the developer tools panel by moving the splitter (Sounds strange, but trust me). You don't have to do this if you are sure that you have resized it before. Close all Chrome windows.